# Visual Studio pré build event delete reference

Tags: visual-studio, events, command-line, build, nuget

I'm going to spare you the trouble of explaining why I want to do this, but I'm looking for a way to remove a reference to a dll when a project is build. I'm not talking about an unused reference, but a reference that might contain the same namespaces and the same classes which my project is using. I was thinking of a pré build event command line, but I don't know what the command will look like.

PS: For those of you who do care why I want this. I have a template project A that contains classes that use base classes defined in another project B. This template project (A) its only function is to be packed up in a Nuget package to then be deployed in multiple other projects, for simplicity sake imagine 3 projects C, D and E. Using the Nuget in projects C, D & E will generate all the classes and put a reference to the dll of project B, because we need the Base classes. At the moment I also get a reference to the DLL of template project (A). This is what should not happen because all classes with the same namespaces will exist in project A and in projects C, D & E. This is why I want to automatically remove the reference to the template project (A).

Thanks in advance.

Kind regards,

Yannick

Comment: Why do you need a reference to the Package A, if it's not going to be used at all?

There are multiple ways to "fix" your problem, but I'd strongly discourage from going the direction of excluding the assembly from compile. 

The nice approach here would be to have a different namespace in A, especially if you control both. 

A second approach would be adding a global alias for the referenced project/packages. 

Example:

    <Reference Include="MyLibrary">
      <HintPath>path\to\MyLibrary.dll</HintPath>
      <Aliases>CoolLibrary</Aliases>
    </Reference>

Comment: @imps, I didn't need the reference to project A, just like I said. The problem was that I was always getting the reference because I always used the includereferencedprojects argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Visual Studio pré build event delete reference

Do you want to delete the reference `project A` in the build event command line when you build the project? If yes, I am afraid there is no directly build event command line to do this, you can create a power shell script to delete the reference, then execute this power shell script in the build event.

However, just as imp said "*Why do you need a reference to the Package A, if it's not going to be used at all?*". So as a workaround, you can not add reference `project A` to the project C, D and E, To accomplish this, you can target the dll files to the tools folder instead of lib folder in the `.nupsec` file:

```
  <files>
    <file src="bin\Debug\ProjectA.dll" target="Tools\ProjectA.dll" />
  </files>
```

The `.nuspec` of `Project A` should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>MyModels</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>Tester</authors>
    <owners>Tester</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Package description</description>
    <releaseNotes>Summary of changes made in this release of the package.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2018</copyright>
    <tags>Tag1 Tag2</tags>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="bin\Debug\ProjectB.dll" target="lib\Net45\ProjectB.dll" />
    <file src="bin\Debug\ProjectA.dll" target="Tools\ProjectA.dll" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Then pack this `.nuspec` file, generate the nuget package, install this package to the project, the reference Project A will not be added to the project.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was always creating my nuget package with the includereferencedprojects argument. Not doing this & specifying which dependencies & files should be used solved it. I did this the same way as your targetting the lib\net45 folder. I will mark your post as the answer, but could you maybe explain what the target Tools folder does exactly?